# How to prevent data extraction from rooted phone via adb?

Tags: security, adb, root-access

I've a question regarding security in a rooted device.

Being superuser means that you can access the /data/data directory, and that's a lot of personal data (I think it is almost all the data there can be in the phone).

So if a rooted phone is stolen, anyone can connect to the device via adb and perform a complete "audit" of the data, including mail, sms, search and browser history, contacts, etc. It is in fact easier than with a non-rooted phone. I see a big vulnerability here.
Is there a way to prevent adb connecting to the phone like, for instance, a password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adb can connect to an android device only if "USB debugging" is enabled in Settings->Applications->Development. If this setting is disabled and a password lock is set for unlocking the device, there should be no worries.

Also there are many apps such 'Lookout' which provide the ability to remotely wipe data from a phone if it gets stolen.